# running curl on dockerfile but getting error because of missing dependency

Tags: docker, curl

Trying to run curl from within my container but getting this error, i already copied into the container after installing curl so not sure what I am missing

```
FROM debian:stretch

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      build-essential \
      cmake \
      curl \
      make \
      wget \
      unzip \
      bash \
      jq \
      libssl1.0-dev \
      libasl-dev \
      libsasl2-dev \
      pkg-config \
      libsystemd-dev \
      zlib1g-dev


COPY /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so* /lib/x64_64-linux-gnu/`
```

`docker run -it --env LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/x64_64-linux-gnu/" myimage .`

```
#curl
curl: error while loading shared libraries: libcom_err.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Seems it can't find `libcom_err.so`, not sure it have to do with curl. What base image do you use? Could you show the whole file or a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce it?

Comment: @Jite updated the post

Comment: using `debian:stretch` image

Comment: May I ask why you copy the `libcom-err2` package from your local machine instead of installing it with apt as the other packages? :)

Comment: installed `libcomerr2` but still getting same error of not found :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to copy it, just add it to the `apt install` phase, and let apt figure out how to get it and resolve dependencies for it:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      build-essential \
      cmake \
      curl \
      make \
      wget \
      unzip \
      bash \
      jq \
      libcomerr2 \
      libssl1.0-dev \
      libasl-dev \
      libsasl2-dev \
      pkg-config \
      libsystemd-dev \
      zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: tried with copying the libcom_err files over and without

Comment: looks like i copied it to the wrong folder, had to be same as my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  thanks!